# Why playstore does not show localized description?

Tags: android, localization, google-play

I've an application in google playstore. It has a default app description in English. Recently I've added a second language (French) through **Store Listing**. I've added my own text, didn't use the automatic translation.

But whenever I set my device language to French and go to playstore, it still shows the English description. Why the description is not shown in French? Moreover, though I've added my app name in French, when I search in playstore I cannot find my app. Someone please put light onto this.

Answer (score 2):

Google Play Localization does not work on Phone Language.

It works on your present country, that you are trying to access playstore from.
If you want to test this, use France VPN and then open playstore app.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm using Xiaomi device. I've also selected my Locale as **France**. Still not working. :(

Comment: Its not about device,, its about the internet location you are using.

Comment: I haven't got the approval mail from play console yet. Should I wait for that?

Comment: Could not understand your last comment? Is it related?